# Jquery ui resizable rescale background-image

Tags: jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a `div` with a background image, I'm allowing the user to rescale the `div` using `Jquery UI's resizable` function. I was hoping the background image would scale when the user resizes the `div`. But this doesn't happen. Is there an easy way to fix this?

I found some other examples where they used an `<img>` tag inside the `div` for it. But I really wanted to use CSS for the background-image.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="settingsWidget" class="SarahComponent">

    </div>           
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.SarahComponent {
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
}

#settingsWidget {
    background: URL('../../img/advancedsettings.png') no-repeat;
    padding:40px;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#settingsWidget").resizable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css("border", "");
}

});
$("#settingsWidget").draggable({ cursor: "move" });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `background-size` to a percentage:

> Sets the width and height of the background image in percent of the
>   parent element. The first value sets the width, the second value sets
>   the height. If only one value is given, the second is set to "auto"

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for more information about the `background-size` property.

**CSS:**

```
#settingsWidget {
  background: URL('https://placehold.it/68x68') no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  padding:40px;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/xsdtphrg/2/)**